# Global variable wrapped in a function

Tags: scope, julia, scoping

I'm learning Julia as part of my PhD in economics but I've come across an issue that doesn't make sense to me. I'm trying to write a function that performs some preliminary calculations then conducts a while loop and returns some value. I want to do this without using global variables. For some reason I can't get it to work. See the minimal working example below which returns a undefined variable error for `z`.

```
function test_me(n)
x = 2 + 1
y = x - 1 
i = y
while i <= n 
    println(i)
    i += 1
    z = 3*i
end 
return z 
end
```

I can solve the problem easily by making `z` a global variable.

```
function test_me2(n)
x = 2 + 1
y = x - 1 
i = y
while i <= n 
    println(i)
    i += 1
    global z = 3*i
end 
return z 
end
```

I'm confused as I was under the impression that by wrapping the while loop in a function implies that `z` is in the local scope and the global declaration is unnecessary. For example the code below works as expected.

```
function test_me3(n)
i = 1
while i <= n 
    println(i)
    i += 1
    z = 3*i
end 
return z 
end
```

I apologise if this issue is trivial. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not a julia pro (yet), but: the function is flawed in one sense that `z` is not initialized outside of `while`, so it is possible that `z` will never be assigned (e.g., `test_me3(0)`). Perhaps assign `z = 0` before the while loop?

Comment: (I will add that setting `z=0` is arbitrarily assign a value to `z`. If there is feasibility that the function will *legitimately* return a zero to valid data, then `z=0` is the wrong initialization value. Perhaps @crstnbr's recommendation for `local z` is better.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a `local z` or alternatively a `z = 0` before your while loop such that `z` is defined in the loop.

For more on this check out the [scoping page of the Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#scope-of-variables-1) and the [`local` keyword docstring](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/base/#local).

See also this question/answer: [In Julia, is there a way to pass a variable from a local scope to the enclosing local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788621/in-julia-is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-variable-from-a-local-scope-to-the-enclosing/57790305#57790305)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Certainly using `z=0` solves the problem as both of you have suggested. However I can't seem to get the `local z` to work. I'll need to do more reading around the subject I think.